# Построение nested sets дерева состоящего из collapse\spoiler

Tags: php, алгоритм, yii2, nested-sets

В БД имеется структура данных Nested sets и проект с использованием yii2/
Нужно отобразить эту структуру, в виде вложенных друг в друга `Collapse`.

Вот так выглядит структура отсортированная по RGT:
[image: Nested sets sorted by rgt]

В итоге должно получится следующее:

```
-*spoiler*  
--*spoiler*  
--*spoiler*  
----*spoiler*  
-*spoiler*  
--*spoiler*   
----*spoiler*  
-*spoiler*   
-*spoiler*   
-*spoiler*   
-*spoiler*   
-*spoiler*   
-*spoiler*  
-*spoiler*  
--*spoiler*   
-*spoiler*
```

Добавление спойлера происходит следующим образом. Это yii2 виджет, который возвращает верстку спойлеров, с уже наложенными стилями и проставленными `id` по которым будет осуществлятся js-сворачивание-разворачивание :

```
private static function createCollapse($label, $content)
{
    return Collapse::widget(
        [
            'items' => [
                [
                    //В таблице поле LABEL
                    'label' => $label,
                    //В качестве контента ID записи
                    'content' => $content
                ]
            ]
        ]
    );
}
```

Верстка выглядит *примерно* так:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title"><a class="collapse-toggle collapsed" href="#w7-collapse7" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#w7" aria-expanded="false">Main Spoiler</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="w7-collapse7" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="w6" class="panel-group collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style="">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title"><a class="collapse-toggle collapsed" href="#w6-collapse1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#w6" aria-expanded="false">Sub spoiler</a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="w6-collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title"><a class="collapse-toggle collapsed" href="#w6-collapse2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#w6" aria-expanded="false">Sub Spoiler</a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="w6-collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            content
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как я понимаю, просто пройти из корня по всем детям не получится, потому что каждый верхний виджет-спойлер уже должен знать о своем содержании, которое может в свою очередь состоять из неограниченного количества таких же виджетов-спойлеров, и так до бесконечности.

Один из вариантов решения - одним запросом получить таблицу отсортированную по RGT, и проверять текущий LVL на 3 случая - больше\меньше\равно - [пример реализации с `<ul><li>`](https://gist.github.com/ale10257/19fa0f0e20569a83e15e1e43179e7121). Но я никак не могу адаптировать этот пример под использование виджета :(

Второй вариант, как предложил @fedornabilkin, но `nested sets` не хранят в себе `parent id`, и опять же, возникает трудность с оборачиванием в `Collapse::widget`

Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: давайте коротко и ясно, пример дерева (данных) и пример вывода (хтмл)?

Comment: @teran добавил примеры.

Comment: и почему эту функцию нельзя рекурсивно запустить?

Comment: я сейчас думаю над таким решением, но результаа пока нет :(  
Один из минусов - это очень большое количество запросов к БД. Получается на каждом шаге рекурсии я должен обращаться в БД за количеством детей или родителей. И пока непонятно с какой стороны лучше начать от родителей, и идти вниз по детям, или же наоборот?

Comment: если виджет ходит в БД в каждый, то не пользуйтесь им, постройте вручную. Есть там в yii шаблонизатор ведь? рекурсивно шаблоны он может выполнять?

Comment: нет - виджет в бд не ходит.В БД хожу я :) Видимо потому что не до конца понимаю алгоритм
Виджету нужно в `content` передать либо текст, либо кусок верстки который будет содержать уже спойлеры.

Comment: Удобнее будет создать список массивов чтобы в итоге получилась двумерная матрица в том виде как вы её вывели в примере. Каждый виджет так сможет получить свою субматрицу и передавать её внутрь для построения нижележащих виджетов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, немного разобравшись с рекурсией и `nested sets` было написано вот такое решение:

1. Получаем дерево, которое нужно отрисовать, одним запросом из бд:

   SELECT * FROM table WHERE ROOT = $root ORDER BY lft
2. Далее, создадим вспомогательные функции для поиска потомков и фильтрации дерева по `LVL`:

   ```
   /**
    * Выделяет из дерева $tree потомков узла $node
    *
    * @param Tree[] $tree Массив узлов дерева для фильтрации
    * @param Tree $node Узел дерева потомки которого будут возвращены
    * @return Tree[]|[]
    */
   public static function filterChildren(array $tree, Tree $node)
   {
       return array_filter(
           $tree,
           function ($element) use ($node) {
               return $element->LFT > $node->LFT
                   && $element->RGT < $node->RGT
                   && $element->ROOT === $node->ROOT;
           }
       );
   }

   /**
   * Фильтрация дерева по параметру LVL;
   * Результирующий массив будет содержать только узлы с уровнем `$lvl`
   *
   * @param Tree[] $tree Массив узлов дерева для фильтрации
   * @param int $lvl Уровень по которому осущесвляется фильтрация
   * @return Tree[]
   */
   public static function filterByLvl(array $tree, $lvl)
   {
       return array_filter(
           $tree,
           function ($element) use ($lvl) {
               return $element->LVL === $lvl;
           }
       );
   }
   ```
3. Метод для рендеринга коллапсов, по сути, для сокращения кода:

   ```
   private static function createCollapse(Tree $node, $content)
   {
       return Collapse::widget(
           [
               'items' => [
                   [
                       'label' => $node->NAME,
                       'content' => $content
                   ]
               ]
           ]
       );
   }
   ```
4. Сама рекурсивная функция будет выглядеть вот так:

   ```
   /**
   * Рендеринг дерева в виде спойлеров.
   *
   * Метод возвращает HTML верстку дерева выполненную в виде вложенных друг в друга спойлеров.
   *
   * @param array $roots Массив узлов дерева для которых необходимо построить спойлеры
   * @param array $fullTree Полное дерево, включая детей и предков всех элементов
   *
   * @return string
   */
   public static function renderAsCollapses(array $roots, array $fullTree)
   {
       $collapses =  '';
       foreach ($roots as $key =>  $node) {
           /** @var Tree $node */
           //Проверка на наличие потомков
           if ($node->RGT - $node->LFT > 1) {
               $collapses .= self::createCollapse(
                   $node,
                   self::renderAsCollapses(
                       ClassifierTree::filterChildren($fullTree, $node),
                       $fullTree,
                   )
               );
           } else {
               $collapses .= self::createCollapse(
                   $node,
                   'content'
               );
           }
       }
       return $collapses;
   }
   ```

**Использование:**

```
    //$tree содержит массив элементов дерева, полученный из БД с помощью запроса
    //SELECT * FROM table WHERE ROOT = $root ORDER BY lft 
    $collapses = TreeViewHelper::renderAsCollapses(
        //Для корректной работы функции, первым аргументом необходимо передать
        //массив корневых элементов, для которого будет строится дерево.
        //Начинать построение можно от любого уровня вложенности.
        Tree::filterByLvl($tree, 1),
        $tree,
    );
```

Немного странным выглядит то, что в функцию нужно передавать два массива. Это сделано для того, что бы при первом вызове функции спойлеры отрисовывались только для корневых элементов. Если же в функцию передать всё дерево целиком, то функция рендеринга выполнится вообще для каждого узла дерева. В таком случае на выходе мы получим столько спойлеров, сколько элементов в нашем дереве, плюс каждый элемент имеющий потомков так же будет содержать в себе вложенные спойлеры. Возможно этой проблемы можно избежать более лаконичным способом, но я, к сожалению, не смог его найти. Буду рад если кто то подскажет.

Единственное, что меня смущает в этом решении, это вопрос о переполнении стэка. На сколько большой должна быть вложенность, что бы переполнился стэк?

Answer (score 2):

Полагаю, что надо одним запросом получить все данные. Затем подготовить многомерный массив, в который разложить потомков для каждого родителя.

```
$cats = [];
foreach($rows as $model){
    $cats[$model->parent][] = $model;
}
```

А затем этот массив скинуть в рекурсивный метод. Что-то типа такого для построения списков в виде дерева.

```
public static function createTree($cats, $parent)
{
    if(isset($cats[$parent]) && is_array($cats[$parent])) {
        $tree = '<ul>';
        foreach ($cats[$parent] as $model) {
            $tree .= '<li>' . $model->title;
            $tree .= self::createTree($cats, $model->id);
            $tree .= '</li>';
        }
        $tree .= '</ul>';
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Во вьюшке вызываем метод `echo className::createTree($cats, 1);`

**UPD**
Для наглядности можно выполнить пример кода:

```
$rows = [];
$rows[] = ['id' => 1, 'title' => 'title 1', 'parent' => 0];
$rows[] = ['id' => 2, 'title' => 'title 2', 'parent' => 0];
$rows[] = ['id' => 3, 'title' => 'title 1 1', 'parent' => 1];
$rows[] = ['id' => 4, 'title' => 'title 1 2', 'parent' => 1];
$rows[] = ['id' => 5, 'title' => 'title 1 2 1', 'parent' => 4];
$rows[] = ['id' => 6, 'title' => 'title 1 2 2', 'parent' => 4];
$rows[] = ['id' => 7, 'title' => 'title 3', 'parent' => 0];
$rows[] = ['id' => 8, 'title' => 'title 3 1', 'parent' => 7];
$rows[] = ['id' => 9, 'title' => 'title 3 2', 'parent' => 7];

foreach($rows as $model){
    $cats[$model['parent']][] = $model;
}

function createTree($cats, $parent)
{
    if(isset($cats[$parent]) && is_array($cats[$parent])) {
        $tree = '<ul>';
        foreach ($cats[$parent] as $model) {
            $tree .= '<li>' . $model['title'];
            $tree .= createTree($cats, $model['id']);
            $tree .= '</li>';
        }
        $tree .= '</ul>';
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
    return $tree;
}

echo createTree($cats, 0);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этот вариант подразумевает только двойную вложенность, а у меня вложенность неограничена :(

Comment: Это меня прям оскорбило. Добавил код для примера и скрин с результатом вывода. Рекурсия ж.

Comment: Коллега, приношу свои извинения, и спасибо за ответ! Изначально не совсем понял ваш код, но с обновлением и примером стало гораздо понятнее. Но тут есть несколько нюансов: 1) nested sets не хранит в своих записях данные о parentID, соответственно подготовить многомерный массив используя один запрос, как вы предлагаете - не получится.
2) Обернуть тегами `<li>` и `<ul>`  получается гораздо проще, чем обернуть в виджет. Как я понимаю, каждый виджет верхнего уровня уже должен свое содержание. Задача усложняется тем, что на каждом уровне может быть такое же неограниченное количество виджетов.

Comment: Это все надуманные проблемы. Если узел не хранит id родителя, его можно получить по левым и правым ключам. У родителя левый ключ всегда меньше, а правый всегда больше. Уровень, соответственно на единицу меньше. При выборке данных, можно создать виртуальное поле (свойство модели) и туда записать ид родителя. Рекурсивный метод позволит обработать любое количество уровней.

Answer (score 1):

Вот такая функция возвращает всё дерево в виде многомерного массива с добавлением parent_id каждому элементу для удобства. Работает с любым количеством деревьев и любой степенью вложенности.
Далее из этого массива можно сделать что угодно.
Используется один запрос к базе. Перебор уровня вложенности можно менять с помощью level. Так же можно обратиться к определенному дереву, добавив в запрос
where(['root' => $root]).
Если в вашей таблице используется под уровни 'depth' вместо 'lvl', поменяйте
$l = $node['lvl']; на $l = $node['depth']; Соответственно также $r = $node['root']; на $r = $node['tree'], если вместо 'root' в базе 'tree'.
Если таблица без использования множества деревьев, тогда $r = 1;

```
$category = CategoryMenu::find()->orderBy('root, lft')->indexBy('id')
  ->asArray()->all();

function getTree($category, $level = 0) {
    $tree = []; $_id = [];
    foreach ($category as $id=>&$node) {
        $l = $node['lvl']; $p = $l-1; $r = $node['root']; 
        $_id[$r][$l] = $id;
        if ($l == $level) {
            $tree[$id] = &$node;
        } elseif ($l > $level) {
            $category[$_id[$r][$p]]['childs'][$id] = &$node;
            $node['parent_id'] = $category[$_id[$r][$p]]['id'];
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```